# Custom View cannot ignores .frame() modifier in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to create a custom view in SwiftUI that looks like this:

```
struct CanvasRowView: View {
    
var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
        ForEach(viewModel.canvasElements) { canvasElement in
            switch canvasElement.type {
            case .image:
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    
            case .spacer:
                Spacer()
                    
            case .placeholder:
                Color.blue
                    .frame(width: 3, height: 10)
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

So far so good, but when I'm trying to add `.frame(100, 100)` to the above `View`, the modifier is ignored and the view has a size of 0.
Also, I tried to wrap the code inside of `GeometryReader` but it seems that it sets the size of maximum available and this is also something I am not looking for.

To be more specific I am looking for my my custom `View` to have a intrinsic content size (much like `HStack` behaves)

Edit: The way I use it (e.g in a Preview or in another preview)

```
CanvasRowView()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
```

Also worth mentioning is that when I have elements in `viewModel.canvasElements` (the property is `ForEach`ed) everything is working as expected. The problem only comes when HStack is empty.

Comment: This really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: “the view has a size of 0.” How do you know the view has a size of 0? How are you measuring it?

Comment: Either in preview inspector. Also, for debug purposes I set `.background(Color.red)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `.frame(width: 100, height: 100)` at the end of CanvasRowView.body, then CanvasRowView will have a size of 100x100. The HStack will still have a size of zero if there are no elements. An HStack is **always** the size of its elements (plus spacing). You cannot change the size of an HStack other than by changing the size of its content. But if you want CanvasRowView to be a particular size, you would wrap the HStack in a `frame` to set that, since Frames determine their size based on their parameters.

You may be misunderstanding how `frame` works. It does not set the size of a View. It **is** a View. It has a size, and it offers that size to its content (which then chooses its own size), and then the Frame positions the content inside itself. There is no general way to set a View's size. Every View sets its own size, often based on the size its parent offered.

Comment: Oh Wow really dumb of me to expect the HStack to have a frame of (100, 100) since yeah, I was setting the size on another element. Thanks for helping me figure it out.